# How can I get the content of a Windows 10 ?Notification in a UWP/C#?

Tags: c#, uwp, notifications, windows-10

I'm trying to get the text inside user notifications, and the action that occurs if you click the notification. I get the user's permission to read them (using `UserNotificationListener.RequestAccessAsync()`), and then I iterate over them, and add them to a ListView:

```
private async void getNotificationsAsync()
{
    UserNotificationListener listener = UserNotificationListener.Current;
    IReadOnlyList<UserNotification> notifs = await listener.GetNotificationsAsync(NotificationKinds.Toast);
    NotificationsList.Items.Clear();
    foreach (UserNotification notif in notifs)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(notif.AppInfo.DisplayInfo.DisplayName);
        NotificationsList.Items.Add(notif.AppInfo.DisplayInfo.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

But all I can get from the [UserNotification class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.usernotification?view=winrt-19041) is the initiating application's name (and the time the notification occured). I can't find any way to access the content of the notification in the `UserNotification` class.

Is what I'm trying possible? Am I using the right class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! (always happens **after** I ask the question ). For posterity's sake, here's the answer:

```
NotificationBinding toastBinding = notif.Notification.Visual.GetBinding(KnownNotificationBindings.ToastGeneric);

if (toastBinding != null)
{
    // And then get the text elements from the toast binding
    IReadOnlyList<AdaptiveNotificationText> textElements = toastBinding.GetTextElements();

    // Treat the first text element as the title text
    string titleText = textElements.FirstOrDefault()?.Text;

    // We'll treat all subsequent text elements as body text,
    // joining them together via newlines.
    string bodyText = string.Join("\n", textElements.Skip(1).Select(t => t.Text));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.
Platform Support: Ensure that the platform you are working on supports the UserNotificationListener and related features. Not all platforms may have the same level of support for these notification features.

use WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation)
Add user notification listener to properties from package.appxmanifest

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!